# Sum Union Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find how many times a user appears in two different tables ... for now I used a union

I have this Query And I Want to do A `SUM` of my record

```
(SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta
FROM sn_like_spotted s
GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, s.id ASC
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta2
FROM sn_like_risposta s
GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, s.id ASC
)
```

My result:

```
p  conta

1   33
2   15
3   1
4   11
5   2
1   20
2   9
4   2
9   2
18  5
19  7
```

And I Want the p with max Sum of conta

The result should be

```
p  conta

1   53
2   24
4   13
19   7
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery!

```
SELECT p, SUM(conta) AS conta 
FROM (
  SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta
  FROM sn_like_spotted s
  GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta2
  FROM sn_like_risposta s
  GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
) AS baseview
GROUP BY p
ORDER BY conta DESC, p ASC
```

**EDIT**

I cust/pasted your original query, which produced bad ordering - fixed now.

Comment: thanks for reply but i have this error `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mySQL but don't you want to union the results set together and then to do the group by?

Conceptually somthing like

```
SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta
from
((SELECT s.proprietario_id as p
FROM sn_like_spotted s

)
UNION ALL
(SELECT s.proprietario_id as p
FROM sn_like_risposta s

))
GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, s.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `p` with the max sum:

```
select p, sum(conta) as conta
from ((SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta
       FROM sn_like_spotted s
       GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, COUNT(*) as conta
       FROM sn_like_risposta s
       GROUP BY s.proprietario_id  
      )
     ) u
GROUP BY p
ORDER BY sum(conta) DESC, s.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `limit 1` gets you the highest value.  Note that the `order by` in the subqueries is unnecessary, you only need the order by in the outer query.

Also, in a `union`, the columns are named after the names in the first `select`.  The alias `conta2` is a bit out-of-place, because that column is called `conta`.

By the way, you can also write the query without the aggregations in the subqueries:

```
select p, sum(conta) as conta
from ((SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, 1 as conta
       FROM sn_like_spotted s
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT s.proprietario_id as p, 1 as conta
       FROM sn_like_risposta s
      )
     ) u
GROUP BY p
ORDER BY sum(conta) DESC, s.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Under some circumstances, this might even have better performance.